# gdbus introspect with --recurse AND --xml options together do not recurse

Tags: dbus, gdbus

I would like to recursively explore an interface with the --recurse

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest "org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1" --object-path "/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1" --recurse
```

add out put the result as XML with the  --xml option

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest "org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1" --object-path "/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1" --xml
```

However both together only give the top level interface as XML

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest "org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1" --object-path "/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1" --recurse --xml
```

The end goal is using this file with CreateInterface in java-dbus to create my class files. (That does not have a recursion option for its object-path file generation.)

Is there a way of recursively generating the dbus introspection XMLfile?
I am on Redhat 7 BTW.